# Inkscape: How to choose font replacement?

Tags: fonts, pdf, inkscape

Every decent drawing/vectorial software like Adobe Illustrator or CorelDraw shows-up a dialogue asking how would you like to replace the fonts type-faces that it wasn't able to find on the system, something like this:

[Illustrator Font Replacement Dialogue](http://blogassets.globalizationpartners.com/imgs/blog/find-font.png)

I cannot find a way do it in **Inkscape**. When I try to open or import a AI or PDF file it only shows "Replace PDF Fonts by closest-named installed fonts" which doesn't works very well. Does anyone knows how could I use such a feature?

Comment: Good question. I normally edit the svg file by hand (or `sed`).

Answer (score 5):

In Inkscape 0.91 there is an extension called "Replace font" (find it under Extensions -> Text). It can list all the used fonts in the document, and you can do a find & replace for specific fonts, or replace all fonts by one of your choice. (Note that you have to fill in the font names by hand, or copy-paste, there's no drop down to choose from).